# Erasing pixels from image and then reverting them back

Tags: swift

I'm creating an eraser app where i have a picture and the user can erase the background with the following func :

```
  func eraseImage( image: UIImage ,line: [CGPoint] ,brushSize: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(proxy.size, false, 0)
        
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        
        let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy!.size.height))

        //lassoImageView.image?.draw(in: calculateRectOfImageInImageView(imageView: lassoImageView))
        image.draw(in: rect, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
        
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: line.first!.x - 50, y: line.first!.y - 50))
        for pointIndex in 1..<line.count {
            context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line[pointIndex].x - 50, y: line[pointIndex].y - 50))
        }
        
        context?.setBlendMode(.clear)
        context?.setLineCap(.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(brushSize)
        context?.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0), blur: 8)
        context?.strokePath()
                
        
        if let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
            return img
        }
        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return nil
    }
```

I'm struggling with figuring out how can i add a drawing function where the user can correct it's earaser mistake and draw back some parts.
I'm thinking of drawing on the edited image the original image with a mask of the path which tracks the cgpoints of the users location. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up your image with a second CALayer installed as a mask. Install an image view into the mask layer's contents, and draw with clear/opaque colors into the mask to mask/expose pixels from the image layer.

Comment: I was able to use a CALayer mask to clear out part of the image but how would I expose those parts back if use draws on them?

Comment: I always get confused about which way mask images work. I **think** opaque pixels in the mask reveal the image and clear pixels hide the image. Thus, if the user un-erases, just restore the mask pixels to opaque. Likewise if the user draws with a new color, you'd draw those pixels into the image, and set the mask pixels at that location to opaque to un-mask them again.